# Get value from one of many dictionaries in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I can't figure out how to get a specific value from a json response. Here is what I get from the API I am using:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "quote_precision": 18,
      "priority": 13,
      "market_rate": 6.8e-5,
      "is_traded": true,
      "is_admin_only": false,
      "id": "dc5c9c86-9bd1-4f41-bdb2-db3828a4de44",
      "display_size_precision": 8,
      "display_price_precision": 8,
      "code": "CREDO-ETH",
      "base_precision": 18
    },
    {
      "quote_precision": 2,
      "priority": 0,
      "market_rate": 0.07,
      "is_traded": true,
      "is_admin_only": false,
      "id": "21edc8e8-3179-4778-bd9e-9eb70221c982",
      "display_size_precision": 8,
      "display_price_precision": 2,
      "code": "CREDO-USD",
      "base_precision": 18
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

How can I get market_rate from each block separately? Thanks.

Comment: [ d["market_rate"] for d in globalDict["data"] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to "market_rate" with:

```
>>> for book in some_dict["data"]:
...     print (book["market_rate"])
... 
6.8e-05
0.07
```

Or if you want to create the new array with data:

```
>>> [book["market_rate"] for book in some_dict["data"]]
[6.8e-05, 0.07]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have dictionary containing an entry called "data". Data is a list of dictionaries. You can iterate over this list. Assuming you assign the json response to someDict:

```
data_list = someDict["data"]
for d in data_list:
    print (d["market_rate"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 dict = {
  "data": [
    {
      "quote_precision": 18,
      "priority": 13,
      "market_rate": 6.8e-5,
      "is_traded": True,
      "is_admin_only": False,
      "id": "dc5c9c86-9bd1-4f41-bdb2-db3828a4de44",
      "display_size_precision": 8,
      "display_price_precision": 8,
      "code": "CREDO-ETH",
      "base_precision": 18
    },
    {
      "quote_precision": 2,
      "priority": 0,
      "market_rate": 0.07,
      "is_traded":True,
      "is_admin_only": False,
      "id": "21edc8e8-3179-4778-bd9e-9eb70221c982",
      "display_size_precision": 8,
      "display_price_precision": 2,
      "code": "CREDO-USD",
      "base_precision": 18
    }
  ]
}
for i in dict["data"]:
  print(i["market_rate"])
```

Output:

6.8e-05

0.07